# Problems with grid, probably with height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

What is shown in the layout:

[image: layout]

And what I've done:

[image: my work]

Code:

```css
.portfolio__items{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
  gap: 15px;
}

.portfolio__item-img{
  background: #EDEDED;
  border: 12px solid rgba(237, 237, 237, 1);
  color: #EDEDED;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio__item-img:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(36, 33, 33, 0.8), rgba(36, 33, 33, 0.8)), #EDEDED;
  border: 12px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
}

.portfolio__item-img-1, .portfolio__item-img-2{
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.portfolio__item-img-3, .portfolio__item-img-4, .portfolio__item-img-5{
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.portfolio__item-img-6, .portfolio__item-img-7{
  grid-column-start: 3;
}

.portfolio__item-img-8, .portfolio__item-img-9{
  grid-column-start: 4;
}

.portfolio__item-img-1{
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}

.portfolio__item-img-2{
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}

.portfolio__item-img-3{
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.portfolio__item-img-4{
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}

.portfolio__item-img-5{
  grid-row-start: 7;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}

.portfolio__item-img-6{
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 6;
}

.portfolio__item-img-7{
  grid-row-start: 6;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}

.portfolio__item-img-8{
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.portfolio__item-img-9{
  /* grid-row-start: 4; */
  /* grid-row-end: 10; */
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio__items">
      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-1">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 1</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-2">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 2</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-3">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 3</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-4">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 4</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-5">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 5</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-6">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 6</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-7">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 7</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-8">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 8</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-9">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 9</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Currently, the `.portfolio__item-img-9` element doesn't have any grid properties like `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end` (they are commented out), and if I uncomment them, the properties of the other elements will stop working

I think the reason for my problem is that the parent div `.portfolio__items` doesn't have enough height for its children, but I'm not sure about that.

I've tried to add some more height for it, but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The problem is caused by a lack of a defined height on the container.

```css
.portfolio__items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
  gap: 15px;
  height: 100vh; /* new */
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* to override browser default */
}

.portfolio__item-img {
  background: #EDEDED;
  border: 12px solid rgba(237, 237, 237, 1);
  color: #EDEDED;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio__item-img:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(36, 33, 33, 0.8), rgba(36, 33, 33, 0.8)), #EDEDED;
  border: 12px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
}

.portfolio__item-img-1,
.portfolio__item-img-2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.portfolio__item-img-3,
.portfolio__item-img-4,
.portfolio__item-img-5 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.portfolio__item-img-6,
.portfolio__item-img-7 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}

.portfolio__item-img-8,
.portfolio__item-img-9 {
  grid-column-start: 4;
}

.portfolio__item-img-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}

.portfolio__item-img-2 {
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}

.portfolio__item-img-3 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.portfolio__item-img-4 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}

.portfolio__item-img-5 {
  grid-row-start: 7;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}

.portfolio__item-img-6 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 6;
}

.portfolio__item-img-7 {
  grid-row-start: 6;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}

.portfolio__item-img-8 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}


/* uncommented */

.portfolio__item-img-9 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio__items">
  <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-1">
    <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 1</div>
    <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-2">
    <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 2</div>
    <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-3">
    <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 3</div>
    <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-4">
    <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 4</div>
    <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-5">
    <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 5</div>
    <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-6">
    <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 6</div>
    <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-7">
    <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 7</div>
    <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-8">
    <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 8</div>
    <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-9">
    <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT 9</div>
    <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are the hero of the day!!